# You're in danger of being blocked from asking any more while there is not a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts

Tags: support

According to [the documentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans):

> The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned 
>   if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or 
>   deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.

**Question statistics**

- 9 questions
- 1 deleted
- 3 zero votes of which 1 put on hold as unclear what you're asking

Once the "on hold" status was removed from this question, the warning disappeared when I clicked the *Ask question* button.

**Question**

Why does a danger of being blocked from asking any more message appear while there is not a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you saw that warning, the last *two* questions you'd asked had been closed, one had been deleted, and the other was *eligible* for deletion (the system or potentially other users would've removed it if it hadn't been reopened).

That alone isn't enough to actually cause you any problems. But it's enough to be worth warning you about: if that brief trend had continued, it could've resulted in a very real problem.

That's the purpose of a warning, after all: to *warn* you about something before it actually happens. You did exactly what you should have: you edited your question and saw it reopened, thus removing the need for a warning.